# Return variable from an Ajax call is of invalid type for a JS date object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the server date and time using an Ajax call. I am able to retrieve the value I need, but when I try to use it to create a javascript date object, I get an invalid date error. I tried to use trim to remove any spaces too. Any ideas?

Ajax call:

```
// ajax call to getcurrent server time
$.ajax({
   type: GET',
   url: 'datetime.php',
   success: function(data) {
         console.log("Data: " + data);
         currentdate = new Date($.trim(data));
         console.log("Current date from server: " + currentdate);
  },
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    echo date('y,m,d,H,i,s');
?>
```

Console Output (Chrome):

```
Data: 12,06,08,15,07,57 
Current date from server: Invalid Date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a string as if it were literal code. Kind of like using `eval`, but without actually including the `eval`.

Yes, `eval` is one way to do it: `currentdate = eval("return new Date("+$.trim(data)+");");`

However `eval` is evil. Instead, you should do:

```
var elems = $.trim(data).explode(",");
elems[1]--; // remember months are zero-based in JS
currentdate = new Date(elems[0],elems[1],elems[2],elems[3],elems[4],elems[5]);
```

Even better, though, would be to have your PHP script be `echo time();`, then your JS could be:

```
currentdate = new Date();
currentdate.setTime(data);
```